# Difference Between Invoke and DynamicInvoke

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, invoke, dynamic-invoke

What is the difference between Invoke and DynamicInvoke in delegates? Please give me some code example which explain difference between that two methods.

Comment: If you have multicast delegates (calling multiple delegates contained in the invocation list), there is only `.DynamicInvoke(args)` available.

Answer (score 249, accepted):

When you have a delegate instance, you might know the exact type, or you might just know that it is a `Delegate`. If you know the exact type, you can use `Invoke`, which is **very fast** - everything is already pre-validated. For example:

```
Func<int,int> twice = x => x * 2;
int i = 3;
int j = twice.Invoke(i);
// or just:
int j = twice(i);
```

However! If you just know that it is `Delegate`, it has to resolve the parameters etc manually - this might involve unboxing, etc - a lot of reflection is going on. For example:

```
Delegate slowTwice = twice; // this is still the same delegate instance
object[] args = { i };
object result = slowTwice.DynamicInvoke(args);
```

Note I've written the `args` long hand to make it clear that an `object[]` is involved. There are lots of extra costs here:

- the array
- validating the passed arguments are a "fit" for the actual `MethodInfo`
- unboxing etc as necessary
- reflection-invoke
- then the caller needs to do something to process the return value

Basically, avoid `DynamicInvoke` when-ever you can. `Invoke` is always preferable, unless all you have is a `Delegate` and an `object[]`.

For a performance comparison, the following in release mode outside of the debugger (a console exe) prints:

```
Invoke: 19ms
DynamicInvoke: 3813ms
```

Code:

```
Func<int,int> twice = x => x * 2;
const int LOOP = 5000000; // 5M
var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < LOOP; i++)
{
    twice.Invoke(3);
}
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Invoke: {0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < LOOP; i++)
{
    twice.DynamicInvoke(3);
}
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("DynamicInvoke: {0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Comment: Does it mean that in case of usage the DynamicInvoke compiler produce more IL code to handle delegate invocation?

Comment: @testCoder no, it'll use reflection

Comment: @MarcGravell when I try this in a method which is raising event, I am receiving first method call is taking around 0,7766 ms but second is taking around 0,0568 ms. When first one is Invoke it takes longer than DynamicInvoke or vice versa. When I tried your example with 1 loop and look at ms `Invoke: 0,0478ms, DynamicInvoke: 0,053ms` . Why are you comparing them more than 1 call? And why the first one takes longer than second call of function?

Comment: @uzay95 The first call to the method causes JIT compilation to take place by the CLR--this applies to any method on the first time it's called after the process is started.  In this sort of scenario, you can do one of three things: (1) run the method several times so that the time it took for the first call becomes insignificant in the final result, (2) don't start measuring until after you've called the method once, or (3) use ngen.exe (overkill).  This post explains it well enough... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446203/warm-up-when-calling-methods-in-c-sharp

Comment: @marc-gravell You don't need to create an array to pass to DynamicInvoke since it's method signature states the  [params](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) keyword for the args parameter.