# Execute LambdaExpression and get returned value as object

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

Is there a clean way to do this?

```
Expression<Func<int, string>> exTyped = i => "My int = " + i;
LambdaExpression lambda = exTyped;

//later on:

object input = 4;
object result = ExecuteLambdaSomeHow(lambda, input);
//result should be "My int = 4"
```

This should work for different types.

Comment: Why not just `var func = new Func<int, string>(x => { return string.Format("My int = {0}", x); });`?

Comment: @PoweredByOrange I'm assuming the question is simplified.

Comment: @Kevin Makes sense, otherwise a simple `string.Format()` would do it :)

Comment: Why do you want to use late binding (`DynamicInvoke`). If it is possible, I would try to avoid this (because you have no compile time check; thus it is very much possible you get runtime errors).

Comment: @Styxxy excellent point!  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Sure... you just need to compile your lambda and then invoke it...

```
object input = 4;
var compiledLambda = lambda.Compile();
var result = compiledLambda.DynamicInvoke(input);
```

Styxxy brings up an excellent point...  You would be better served by letting the compiler help you out.  Note with a compiled expression as in the code below input and result are both strongly typed.

```
var input = 4;
var compiledExpression = exTyped.Compile();
var result = compiledExpression(input);
```

Comment: `compiledLambda.Invoke(input);` may be a better choice here if the exact type is known as @Styxxy pointed out. `Invoke` is faster than `DynamicInvoke` due to less reflection going on, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858340/difference-between-invoke-and-dynamicinvoke