# What is the difference between [Delegate].DynamicInvoke and [Delegate].Method.Invoke?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, delegates, invoke

I've write a method to perform an operation in various controls at once, this is the Invoke part in `VBNET`:

```
If [Control].InvokeRequired Then
    [Control].Invoke(ControlAction, [Control])
Else
    ' ControlAction.DynamicInvoke([Control])
    ControlAction.Method.Invoke(ControlAction, {[Control]})
End If
```

But really I don't know which is the difference whether if I use `DynamicInvoke` or `Method.Invoke`.

Maybe `DynamicInvoke` is performed asynchronouslly ...or what?.

I've readed the descriptions of both methods but I still confused and it's unclear for me, I don't know what means "***late-bound***", is a totally strange word for my (and for GoogleTranslator), my english is not good.

> Dynamically invokes (late-bound) the method represented by the current
>   delegate

I need a friendly explanation of all this.

Also I would appreciate much more a code example in `C#` or `VBNET` demonstrating the differences.

Comment: here is full explanation, check Marc's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858340/difference-between-invoke-and-dynamicinvoke

Comment: @Selman22 Thankyou so much, if you want to write something about that I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: i write something, but my english is not so good like you:)

Comment: @Selman22 maybe you could be interested to help in my new one question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535056/perform-an-asynchronous-operation-on-a-set-of-controls-invoking-a-delegate  thanks a lot again!

Comment: i wish i can help but i don't know visual basic =) i know c#..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamicInvoke isn't performed  asynchronously, it's dynamic because your parameters that you pass it to the function checking (and unboxing) in the runtime.Invoke requires exact type of parameters but DynamicInvoke requires an object array which contains your parameters. So you can use DynamicInvoke when you don't know exactly type of the parameter.

Here is full (and better :) explanation about it: [Difference Between Invoke and DynamicInvoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858340/difference-between-invoke-and-dynamicinvoke)