# Invoke instance method statically

Tags: c#, reflection

Let's say there is a class `A` with an parameterless instance method

```
class A
{
    public A(int x) { this.x = x; }
    private int x;
    public int foo() { return x; }
}
```

It's easy to invoke the method using reflection:

```
A a = new A(100);
var method = typeof(A).GetMethod("foo");
var result = method.Invoke(a, new object[0]); // 100
```

However, I want to invoke the method as if it is static

```
var staticmethod = Something(typeof(A), "foo");
var result = staticmethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { a });
```

Is there any way I can get this `staticmethod`?

**NOTE:** I want `Something` to be universal, i.e. `A` can be any class, and `foo` can be any instance method.

**EDIT:** To make things clear:

There is no static method in class `A`.

There is a parameterless instance method called `foo`.

I want to invoke (using `MethodInfo.Invoke`) `foo` AS IF it is a static method, that takes class `A` as the parameter.

**EDIT2:** Why I want this: (to help you understand better)

I have a list of static methods that does similar job for different types, and they are stored in a dictionary `Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo> dict`.

Thus, whenever I have an object `obj` and want to do the job, I can

```
dict[obj.GetType()].Invoke(null, new object[] { obj, param1, param2, ... });
```

Now I want to add instance methods into it as well, but it will require me to remember which methods are static and which methods are instance-bond, and invoke them in different ways:

```
dict[obj.GetType()].Invoke(null, new object[] { obj, param1, param2, ... }); // static methods
dict[obj.GetType()].Invoke(obj, new object[] { param1, param2, ... }); // instance methods
```

Which is inconvenient. So I want to get static `MethodInfo` from instance methods, before adding them into the dict.

**EDIT3:** I don't understand why this question is marked duplicate. The linked page does NOT answer my question. If I'm missing something, please tell me.

The linked page has several answers, but they either

1. requires that I know how many arguments `foo` takes, or
2. gives a method that takes `object[]` as the parameter, instead of a list of parameters.

So none of them fit here.

After some research I found that there's something close to what I need:

```
 A a = new A(100);
 var method = typeof(A).GetMethod("foo");
 var deleg = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<A, int>), method)
 var result = deleg.DynamicInvoke(new object[] { a }); // 100
```

Here, it takes `new object[] { a }` as the argument. But the thing is, since I don't know how foo looks like, how can I pass the first argument of `Delegate.CreateDelegate`?

**Last EDIT:** Found a solution myself. Thank you for your help guys!

Comment: You can invoke static methods with your first method.  In the case of a static method, the first parameter to `Invoke` is ignored.

Comment: @Donnie I don't think that he want to invoke a static method. He try to invoke an instance method like a static method.

Comment: @Donnie I don't want to invoke a static method, what I want is to invoke an instance method using the second approach

Comment: *Invoke the method as if it static* What does that mean exactly? Is the method you're trying to invoke actually static or do you simply don't want to create an instance of `A`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov please see my updated question

Comment: An instance method is an instance method, not a static method, so it cannot be invoked like a static method.  It can only be invoked like an instance method because that's what it is.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://ideone.com/rvUv88) of one thing you can do

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov thanks, but I need to create a whole new class for it... Is there any simpler ways?

Comment: Looks at the answer in which this was marked a duplicate of.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It does not solve my problem as it requires me to know exactly how many parameters foo has, which is impossible.

Comment: What wrong with simple `if` on `MethodInfo.IsStatic`?

Comment: @PetSerAl nothing wrong, but I'm asking if there is a solution to my problem, not if there is an alternative - you can say that I'm trying to study C#

Comment: You can take the class I created an make it static. And invoke the method without creating an instance of it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Static methods and instance methods can be unified by creating a delegate, and then calling `DynamicInvoke`:

```
Dictionary<Type, Delegate> dict = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();

void AddMethod(Type type, String methodName)
{
    var method = type.GetMethod(methodName);
    var types = method.GetParameters().ConvertAll(p => p.ParameterType).ToList();
    if (!method.IsStatic)
        types.Insert(0, type);
    types.Add(method.ReturnType);
    var delegType = Expression.GetFuncType(types.ToArray());
    var deleg = method.CreateDelegate(delegType);
    dict.Add(type, deleg);
}

object GetJobResult(object obj, params object[] additionalParams)
{
    var paramList = additionalParams.ToList();
    paramList.Insert(0, obj);
    return dict[obj.GetType()].DynamicInvoke(paramList.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> but it will require me to remember which methods are static and which methods are instance-bond, and invoke them in different ways

No need to remember it because the method knows this itself:

```
MethodInfo mi = GetTheMethodFromSomewhere();
object[] args = new object[] { obj, param1, param2, … };
if (mi.IsStatic)
    mi.Invoke(null, args);
else
    mi.Invoke(args[0], args.Skip(1).ToArray());
```

Comment: This is exactly what I don't want... You ARE invoking them in different ways

Comment: Well, you *cannot* do it without invoking them differently. They *have* to be invoked differently because they are fundamentally different. Every other way you will come up with (like `DynamicInvoke`) will encapsulate the different invokation in some way too.

Comment: Well I'm not talking about the underlying mechanism of invoking methods, but how to invoke a method by code - and my answer looks just fine. By the way, I really doubt that the underlying mechanism is different, it's just an implicit "this" first parameter

Comment: My point is, since I will be invoking the methods a LOT, I need to do anything to simplify the invoking code - I don't want to write this if-else a thousand times, so I MUST come up with a way to get things unified at the point of adding those methods. Writing another method to encapsulate the difference upon invocation is no-go in my case (although in my answer it's possible)

Comment: @MichaelKim `DynamicInvoke` might *look* fine, but [it’s really not](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12858340/216074). You have *all* the information necessary to decide whether you need to call the method statically or not. Taking the extra route by creating a dynamic delegate will only add a lot of extra burden on the runtime which is unecessary. You haven’t given a single reason why branching the invoke would be a problem, and if you would just wrap that in a method, there is no difference in *using* it; but you get a lot better performance.

Comment: *“I don't want to write this if-else a thousand times”* – So instead, you use the hundreds if-elses and additional checks that are included in DynamicInvoke… since you *“will be invoking the methods a LOT”*, you maybe should look at the performance of your “solution”.

Comment: I don't want to WRITE this if-else a thousand time. I care more about simplification of my code than performance, get it?

Comment: He said you can wrap the logic in a method, so you won't be writing it a thousand times. Get it?