# Referencing various Action<...> variable types with a single type?

Tags: c#, delegates

In my application I have the need to reference various types of `Action`

```
Action action1;
Action<int> action2; 

Action actRef = action2; // Error: actRef is not the same type as action2
```

Basically I would like a type with which I can reference both `action1` and `action2`. Is this possible?

---

The best solution I can think of is to wrap the `Action<...>` in another class that implements some interface.

```
public interface MyInterfaceType
{

}

public class MyActionWrapper : MyInterfaceType
{
    public Action MyAction { get; set; }
}

public class MyActionWrapper<T> : MyInterfaceType 
{
    public Action<T> MyAction { get; set; }
}
```

Then carry around references to `MyInterfaceType`.

```
public class MyActionsHolder
{
    List<MyInterfaceType> MyActions { get; set; }

    public void DoActions()
    {
        foreach(MyInterfaceType anAction in MyActions)
        {
            if(anAction is MyActionWrapper)
                ((MyActionWrapper)anAction).MyAction();
            else if(anAction is MyActionWrapper<int>)
                ((MyActionWrapper<int>)anAction).MyAction(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better solution? Or a way to clean this solution up?

---

More background on the specifics. I have written a simple scripting language which I am trying to parse into `Action`, each `Action` represents a parsed command from the script. As one commentor pointed out I can easily just wrap an `Action` with another

```
Action myParameterlessAction = new Action(() => MySingleParmAction(1));
```

though for a few of my commands I allow the user to supply a psuedo argument/variable. For example I might have an argument `FOO` that allows one argument. The argument is either a value for `FOO` or it is a "variable" meaning the current value of `FOO` when the command is executed.

```
FOO 231     // Set FOO = 231
FOO VAL_FOO // Set FOO to the desired value of FOO, whatever it may be at this time
```

So when I go to parse this second type of command I create an `Action` that takes a parameter so I can supply it when the time comes.

```
Action fooCommand1 = new Action(delegate() { MyForm.SetFooValue(231); });
Action<int> fooCommand2 = MyForm.SetFooValue;
```

I would like to be able to collect all `Action` create from parsing into a `List<...>` that I can then loop over and execute each action.. (I do realize that I will need a method to determine which `Action` need parameters supplied and how to determine what to supply them with; based on my solution above this information would be in `MyInterfaceType` most likely).

---

**EDIT:** In response to @The Anathema's answer, I have a command in my language that allows a user to wait for some period of time before continuing. The parsing of the script to the `Action` would look like this

```
public KeyValuePair<Delegate, object[]> CommandAction { get; set; }
...
Action commandDelegate = new Action(async delegate()
{
    await Task.Delay(msWait);
});
result.CommandAction = new KeyValuePair<Delegate, object[]>(commandDelegate, null);
```

Will `Action.DynamicInvoke` block until the `Task.Delay(...)` has completed? Where will the invocation happen, on the current thread or the thread on which the `Action` was created? Can I change either of these options?

Also per this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12858434/2985796) I take it it would be worthwhile to try to resolve the `Action`s that are parameterless to `Action myAct` so that I can `Invoke` them instead of `DynamicInvoke` (Seeing that `DynamicInvoke` takes orders of magnitude longer to execute per the linked answer)?

Comment: `Object` seem to be perfectly fine option based on your code... Clarifying what you actually want to achieve may help one to suggest approach/alternative.

Comment: How would you supply the parameters to `Action<,,,>`? If you know the parameters in some other location you can just wrap one action with another e.g. `() => MyAction(1)`.

Comment: I have made an edit explaining the background a bit more if you two would like to take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference them as the `Delegate` type.

```
        Delegate action1 = new Action(DoStuff);
        Delegate action2 = new Action<int>(DoStuff2);
```

You can even iterate over an `IEnumerable<Delegate>` and dynamically invoke each of them:

```
        var myActions = new List<Delegate>();
        myActions.Add(action1);
        myActions.Add(action2);

        foreach (var action in myActions)
        {
            action.DynamicInvoke();
        }
```

However, keep in mind that you will get an `TargetParameterCountException` if you're calling one without the appropriate args passed into the DynamicInvoke() method.

You can go a step further and have a dictionary that stores the arguments.

```
        Delegate action1 = new Action(DoStuff);
        Delegate action2 = new Action<int>(DoStuff2);

        var myActions = new Dictionary<Delegate, object[]>();
        myActions.Add(action1, null);
        myActions.Add(action2, new object[] { 0 });

        foreach (var action in myActions)
        {
            action.Key.DynamicInvoke(action.Value);
        }
```

If you need to call the same actions multiple times, change `Dictionary<Delegate, object[]>` to `List<KeyValuePair<Delegate, object[]>>`. This will allow you to have duplicate keys (actions).

Comment: Thank you from the answer I think this solution should work out nicely. // I never realized this, but from your latest edit can I imply that once an `Action` is invoked it cannot be invoked again?

Comment: I have also made a small edit to my post if you could look it over I would be grateful!

Comment: @KDecker, no, I meant that a `Dictionary` enforces unique keys, so sending the same action but with different parameters to the dictionary would fail. `List<KeyValuePair>` allows duplicate keys. You can access the `Action` and invoke it all you want - you just can't add it to the dictionary again.

Comment: Ohh duh, not sure how that went over my head!