# How to make a list of function delegates?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to do something like...
So where there is a list of function delegates and access the 0 index, invoke it and return the value.

```
public static bool methodOne()
{
   return true;
}

var methods_list = new List<Func<Delegate>>();
methods_list.Add( () => methodOne() );

// print true
Console.WriteLine(methods_list[0].Invoke());
```

Comment: `Action`s do not have a return value.

Comment: Please take care to explain what "not working" means.

Comment: @DanielA.White alright.. so what do I use?

Comment: [func delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: There's also no need for `DynamicInvoke`; use `Invoke` or invoke it directly with `methods_list[i]()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/12858434/491907

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a `Func<T>`, so it returns T:

```
void Main()
{
    var methods_list = new List<Func<bool>>();
    methods_list.Add(() => methodOne());

    // prints true
    Console.WriteLine(methods_list[0].Invoke());
}

public static bool methodOne()
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: wow.. that is all it took.. thank you.