# Dynamic parameter in parsed expression

Tags: dynamic-expresso

A quick sample to understand my situation:

```
static Interpreter ParseInterpreter = new Interpreter();
...
var func = ParseInterpreter.Parse("ctx.SomeProp", new Parameter("ctx", typeof(???1)).Compile<Func<???2, object>>;
...
var token = JToken.Parse(s);
dynamic dToken = token;
var obj = func(dToken);
```

In other words, is there a way to pass some dynamic parameter to Parse method and then get a functor which accepts such parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use the `Lambda` class returned by the `Parse` method, and not call the `Compile` function:

```
var interpreter = new Interpreter()
string expression = "ctx.SomeProp";
Lambda parsedExpression = interpreter.Parse(expression, new Parameter("ctx", typeof(object)));
var token = JToken.Parse(s);
var result = parsedExpression.Invoke(token);
```

I have not tested exactly your code but for example I have a test like this that works correctly:

```
dynamic dyn = new ExpandoObject();
dyn.Foo = "bar";
var interpreter = new Interpreter()
    .SetVariable("dyn", (object)dyn);
Assert.AreEqual(dyn.Foo, interpreter.Eval("dyn.Foo"));
```

Consider that this only works on .NET 4.x, on .NET Standard/Core dynamics are not supported.

Comment: Thanks for rapid response! I'd prefer to compile expression due to performance demands. The idea behind all of this is json transformation - JUST library disappointed me greatly under heavy load (and have terrible syntax in transformation rules alongside). Anyway I'll give a try to Lambda and give feedback ASAP.

Comment: @ProfyTroll Internally the expression is always compiled, the difference is that in this case I compile to a Delegate. But performance should be similar. Sometime ago I have done a similar experiment: https://github.com/deltatre-webplu/DynamicExpresso.Template

Comment: Thanks to you, I managed to Compile expression and use JToken dynamically inside. Regarding Delegate vs Func - internally as I see it's Delegate.DynamicInvoke, which should be slower than compiled functor  anyway. Though I must admit that I did not do any measurements and not sure how much slower it is, it might be relatively small difference.

Comment: UPD: Seems somebody did the experiment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858340/difference-between-invoke-and-dynamicinvoke  and I must say the difference is huge