# Is there a way to get an Action taking in any Type as only parameter from a Delegate?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, casting, delegates

I create a `Delegate` from an method I know only takes one parameter and later call it using a `DynamicInvoke`, but I was wondering if it was possible to get an `Action` to invoke directly.

Here is what I have currently:

```
private IEnumerable<MethodInfo> GetMethods()
            => GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);

private IEnumerable<Thing> GetThings() {
    foreach (var method in GetMethods()) {
        var attribute = (MyAttribute) method.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(MyAttribute), false);
        var theDelegate = CreateDelegate(method);

        return new Thing(attribute.Name, theDelegate);
    }
}

private Delegate CreateDelegate(MethodInfo method) {
    Type requestType = method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType,
         actionType = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(requestType);

    return Delegate.CreateDelegate(actionType, this, method);
}

public void Invoke(Thing thing, string json) {
    var requestType = MyDelegate.Method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;
    var o = Deserialize(json, requestType);

    thing.TheDelegate.DynamicInvoke(o);
}
```

Using an Action, [not only would it be faster but it would look much neater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858340/difference-between-invoke-and-dynamicinvoke). The following code **doesn't work** but there must be a way to get something similar:

```
private Action CreateAction(MethodInfo method) {
    Type requestType = method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType,
         actionType = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(requestType);

    return (Action) Delegate.CreateDelegate(actionType, this, method);
}

public void Invoke(Thing thing, string json) {
    Type requestType = MyAction.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;
    var o = Deserialize(json, requestType);

    thing.MyAction(o);
}
```

Comment: How is this different from the original question that you deleted? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55306799/how-to-invoke-methods-from-reflection-with-a-deserialized-json-object?noredirect=1#comment97409320_55306799

Comment: @Enigmativity I just want to know if it's possible, not because of performance issues but out of curiosity. It feels like there must be a way, I just can't figure it out.

Comment: You can use reflection to call in to a strongly-typed method (which gives you want you want I think), but there is no way in a statically-typed language to get a strong-typed reference from a run-time reference.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Action<T>` does not derive from `Action`, you cannot assign an `Action<T>` to `Action`. But both derive from `Delegate`, so you can assign them to `Delegate`.

I fear that you will have to stick to `Delegate` as return type.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/action.cs,486d58da4553e12d) you'll see the following lines:

```
public delegate void Action<in T>(T obj); 
public delegate void Action();
```

`Action` and `Action<T>` *are* delegates, so I don't see a reason why this should be any faster.

But more important: you're code can't work because `Action` simply is no `Action<T>`, it does not take a parameter. They both derive from `Delegate`, but not from each other.

Comment: I know my code can't work it was an example of the type of solution I'm looking for. For the reasons you can see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858340/difference-between-invoke-and-dynamicinvoke)

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know exactly where your `CreateDelegate` method is getting `MethodInfo` from I am going to assume you have direct access to the proper method. So with the following class we can cache a delegate that is invoked with a `string` of json.

```
public sealed class JsonInvoker<T>
{
    private readonly Action<T> _action;

    public JsonInvoker(Action<T> action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public void Invoke(string json)
    {
        var arg = Deserialize(json);
        _action(arg);
    }

    private T Deserialize(string json) => //...
}
```

Then setup your supporting class.

```
private readonly JsonInvoker<DataClass> _dataClassInvoker = 
    new JsonInvoker<DataClass>(DataClass.Process); // Pass the relevant method
```

Comment: That means I need a `JsonInvoker<T>` for every request type? How would I instanciate `_action`? I cannot cast my `Delegate` to `Action`

Comment: @Halhex - Where are you getting the MethodInfo from?

Comment: `GetType().GetMethods(...)` checking if they have a certain attribute.

Comment: @Halhex - Can you post the code that collects those up? I do have a basic idea of how you might pull off something useful.

Comment: I added the code, though I don't see how it would be useful.

Comment: @Halhex - So it looks like you do have access to all the methods in one class but unfortunately it seems like the only way to avoid invoke dynamic is to build up the sequence of Things by hand passing in the delegate directly as seen in my example. Think about it and do what makes sense to you.