# How to run the child-task from parent which is invoking delegate item from delegate collection?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates, task

I am trying to start child tasks from parent and `Invoke()` delegate from collection of delegates in different tasks. But VS is showing me an error - **"Delegate does not contain for Invoke..."** How can i run this code?

```
public struct DataStruct {...}
public class DataClass {...}

public class UserClass
{
          public delegate DataStruct UserDelegateDS();
          public delegate DataClass UserDelegateDC();

          public DataStruct MethodDS()
          {
               return new DataStruct();
          }
          public DataClass MethodDC()
          {
               return new DataClass();
          }
          public void Worker(List<Delegate> delegateCollection)
          {
               Task<object> parent = new Task<object>(() =>
               {
                    var results = new object [delegateCollection.Count];

                    for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
                    {
                         new Task(() => results[i] = delegateCollection[i].Invoke(), TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();
                    }

                    return results;
               });

               var cwt = parent.ContinueWith(pTask => Show(pTask.Result));
               parent.Start();
          }
          void ShowResults(object item) 
          {
               var items = item as object [];
               foreach(var t in items) {...}
          }
          public void Main()
          {
               List<Delegate> delegateCollection = new List<Delegate>();
               UserDelegateDS ds = MethodDS;
               UserDelegateDC dc = MethodDC;
               delegateCollection.Add(ds);
               delegateCollection.Add(dc);
               Worker(delegateCollection);
          }
}
```

problem [screen_from_VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rT3ys.jpg) in Worker() method:

```
new Task(() => results[i] = delegateCollection[i].Invoke(), TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();
```

Comment: You still have [DynamicInvoke](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12858340/1997232).

Comment: The DynamicInvoke() method is also not working for this...

Answer (score 1):

Because type `Delegate` does not specify any function signature, you need to use an actual delegate type to `Invoke` with strong-type.

Consider using only 1 delegate type that has a return type of `object` (for which `System.Func<object>` is recommanded), and wrapping the functions with like `()=>MethodDS()` when assigning to a delegate of such type.

Or if you accept significantly lower performance, you can simply call `DynamicInvoke()` with week-type, instead of `Invoke()` for type `Delegate`