# Delegate DynamicInvoke vs MethodInfo invoke?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection

I recently saw that you can convert a `MethodInfo` into a `Delegate`. But sometimes you may not know what exactly its params or type is. So thats where `Delegate.DynamicInvoke` comes into play.

But whats the difference between `MethodInfo.Invoke` and `Delegate.DynamicInvoke`?
Which is faster and which produces less GC alloc calls ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference Between Invoke and DynamicInvoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858340/difference-between-invoke-and-dynamicinvoke)

Comment: @Lolop No :/ It justs the difference between Delegate.Invoke and Delegate.DynamicInvoke. Furthermore no word of the garbage created

Comment: Are you asking what the difference between `Delegate.DynamicInvoke` and `MethodInfo.Invoke` is? Your title says that, but from your actual question it sounded to me like you were converting your `MethodInfo` into a delegate, and wanted to know the difference between `Delgate.Invoke` and `Delegate.DynamicInvoke`.

Comment: Either way, this would be a good opportunity to benchmark it yourself using [Benchmark.Net](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curiosity did get the better of me so I ended up benchmarking it myself. I still recommend doing it yourself to give it a go and see if you get the same results. If you had a specific situation in mind that might yield different results.

### Results

I was kind of surprised at first, but here they are. I added in a standard `Delegate.Invoke` just to compare.

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MethodInfoInvoke | 116.9913 ns | 1.0848 ns | 1.0148 ns | 0.0024 | - | - | 40 B |
| DelegateDynamicInvoke | 391.8141 ns | 6.6877 ns | 6.2557 ns | 0.0105 | - | - | 176 B |
| DelegateInvoke | 0.4334 ns | 0.0037 ns | 0.0033 ns | - | - | - | - |

As you can see, `MethodInfo.Invoke` is much better than `Delegate.DynamicInvoke`.

This is without considering the cost of converting the `MethodInfo` into a `Delegate` in the first place. Also the `MethodInfo` can just be used on any instance, whereas `Delegate.DynamicInvoke` is locked to a specific instance (Could be wrong on that though, I haven't used `CreateDelegate` before).

And lastly you need to pass the delegate type to `CreateDelegate`, which wouldn't always be easy.

So for less work, you get faster invocation and less garbage generated by using `MethodInfo.Invoke`.

### Benchmark Code

```
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class Benchmark
{
    private MethodInfo MethodInfo { get; set; }
    private Delegate MethodDynamicDelegate { get; set; }
    private Action<int, string> MethodDelegate { get; set; }

    private object[] Params { get; } = new object[] { 0, "Param2" };

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        this.MethodInfo = typeof(Benchmark).GetMethod(nameof(TestMethod));
        this.MethodDynamicDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<int, string>), this, this.MethodInfo);
        this.MethodDelegate = this.TestMethod;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void MethodInfoInvoke()
    {
        this.MethodInfo.Invoke(this, this.Params);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void DelegateDynamicInvoke()
    {
        this.MethodDynamicDelegate.DynamicInvoke(this.Params);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void DelegateInvoke()
    {
        this.MethodDelegate.Invoke(0, "Param2");
    }

    public void TestMethod(int param1, string param2)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :D Well.. i didnt expected this :o I would never have thought that the MethodInfo.Invoke is that faster and cheaper.

Comment: I was definitely surprised as well. If you look at [MethodInfo.Invoke (around like 700)](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/reflection/methodinfo.cs) you'll see they are doing an unsafe call. I wont pretend to understand it, but I assume having all the meta data about the method allows them to skip a lot of checks. I couldn't find the `Delegate.DynamicInvoke` code to compare unfortunately.